# Basic Array Referencing Php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I reference the following dynamic arrays' elements ?

```
$log = array();

$arr1 = array ('a'=>'6:16pm','b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5); 
$arr2 = array ('a'=>'6:24pm','b'=>20,'c'=>30,'d'=>40,'e'=>50); 

$log = array_merge($log, array($arr1['a']=>$arr1));
$log = array_merge($log, array($arr2['a']=>$arr2)); //<-- to use time as key

print_r($log);

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($log); $x++) {
        print_r ($log[0][$x]['a']);  // <-- referencing issue Undefined offset: 0 .. line 20
    }

//------ produces

Array
(
    [6:16pm] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6:16pm
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
            [e] => 5
        )

    [6:24pm] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6:24pm
            [b] => 20
            [c] => 30
            [d] => 40
            [e] => 50
        )

)
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way I'm naming the $log main array.. and there's probably a better way to do what I wish(.. add/ new elements to $log using the time key) - Still a php noob unfortunately. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The for loop says $log[0]  .. ( [$x]['a'] )is undefined. Have tried various combinations...

Comment: So.... Do you have a key in the array called 0? (No you don't).

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to reference a dynamically generated key... so I could determine exactly which log record I need to remove later on. Thanks btw..

Comment: @metokitt Have you tried foreach?

Comment: @vivek_23 I began with foreach, but also couldn't work it out, sorry. Perhaps you could post the foreach loop as the solution ?

Comment: @metokitt You have already got the answers below. You could try that.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear, but just create an array from the two and use the `a` index:

```
$log = array($arr1, $arr2);

foreach($log as $values) {
    echo $values['a'];  // 6:16pm
}
```

Or if you want the time as the index, then re-index on `a`:

```
$log = array($arr1, $arr2);
$log = array_column($log, null, 'a');

foreach($log as $time => $values) {
    echo $time;         // 6:16pm
    echo $values['b'];  // 2
}
```

It's prettier, but there is no need for the time as the index unless you are going to use `ksort` or access by index:

```
echo $log['6:16pm']['b'];
```

Comment: Accepted 2nd solution 'array_column'.

Answer (score 0):

in cases that you don't know your key is recommended that you use foreach statement:

```
$logs = array();

$arr1 = array ('a'=>'6:16pm','b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5); 
$arr2 = array ('a'=>'6:24pm','b'=>20,'c'=>30,'d'=>40,'e'=>50); 

$logs = array_merge($logs, array($arr1['a']=>$arr1));
$logs = array_merge($logs, array($arr2['a']=>$arr2)); //<-- to use time as key

$logs = array();

$arr1 = array('a' => '6:16pm', 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$arr2 = array('a' => '6:24pm', 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30, 'd' => 40, 'e' => 50);

$logs = array_merge($logs, array($arr1['a'] => $arr1));
$logs = array_merge($logs, array($arr2['a'] => $arr2)); //<-- to use time as key


foreach ($logs as $time => $log) {

    //index: 
    print_r($time);
    //array: 
    print_r($log);
    // a array key:
    print_r($log['a']);

    //go through all keys:
    foreach ($log as $letter => $value) {
        //index: 
        print_r($letter);
        //value: a
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I've learned something...(upvote)

Answer (score 0):

You can not call array like

```
print_r ($log[0]);
```

Because your array has key. which is `6:16pm` for first one and `6:24pm` for second. you have to call it by key name you have assigned. your array should be called like this in everywhere even in loop

```
print_r ($log["6:16pm"]);
```